# Unable to open background image file in Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

i am working on a space invaders game, and i have a problem, my background is not working. Here is he code that was necessary, but didn't work:

```
wn = turtle.Screen() 
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.title("Space Invaders")
wn.bgpic('space_invaders_background.gif')
```

and the error message said

'[Running] python -u "d:\USERS\chedl\Documents\Apps\games_and_apps\offline\python\space_invaders\main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\USERS\chedl\Documents\Apps\games_and_apps\offline\python\space_invaders\main.py", line 10, in 
    wn.bgpic('space_invaders_background.gif')
  File "C:\Users\chedl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 1481, in bgpic
    self._bgpics[picname] = self._image(picname)
  File "C:\Users\chedl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\turtle.py", line 479, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename)
  File "C:\Users\chedl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 3539, in **init**
    Image.**init**(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\chedl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 3495, in **init**
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "space_invaders_background.gif": no such file or directory

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.273 seconds'

but the space_invaders_background.gif is in the same file as the actual python application.

Comment: Try providing the full path of the file and see if it helps

Comment: i  did, and it is a file downloaded on my computer

Comment: also, if you want the path, here it is D:\USERS\chedl\Documents\Apps\games_and_apps\offline\python\space_invaders\space_invaders_background.gif

Comment: I don't need this path. You should try using it in your code. I can't hack into your directory ;)

Comment: @Bazingaa how would i do that? sorry for bothering you. I only started half a month ago.

Comment: Replace `wn.bgpic('space_invaders_background.gif')` by `wn.bgpic('D:\USERS\chedl\Documents\Apps\games_and_apps\offline\python\space_invaders\space_invaders_background.gif')`

Comment: now it says : SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: [How to print backslash with Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19095796)

Comment: IT WORKS YEE, THANK YOU SIRE

Answer (score 0):

I will list the documentation needed to change the colors. Furthermore, I do not see how you have a file that is both a gif and a python script. Are you saying the `main.py` and `my.gif` are in the same directory? If so, list the directory name as a full path. What is your OS? Windows? Then full path is `C:\my\path\to\script\my.gif`. If Unix, `/this/is/a/path/and/dir/my.gif`.

Per [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html):

```
turtle.bgcolor(*args)
    Parameters: args – a color string or three numbers in the range 0..colormode or 
    a 3-tuple of such numbers
    Set or return background color of the TurtleScreen.

>>> screen.bgcolor("orange")
>>> screen.bgcolor()
'orange'
>>> screen.bgcolor("#800080")
>>> screen.bgcolor()
(128, 0, 128)

turtle.bgpic(picname=None)
    Parameters: picname – a string, name of a gif-file or "nopic", or None
    Set background image or return name of current backgroundimage. 
    If picname is a filename, set the corresponding image as background. 
    If picname is "nopic", delete background image, if present. 
    If picname is None, return the filename of the current backgroundimage.

>>> screen.bgpic()
'nopic'
>>> screen.bgpic("landscape.gif")
>>> screen.bgpic()
"landscape.gif"
```

Comment: OP is asking about the last line: `wn.bgpic('space_invaders_background.gif')`

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Visual Studio Code, make sure to restart the application and select the folder that contains the python file as the workspace folder like this

Hope this solves your problem